# Sound problem with Ubuntu

Tags: sound

I have a HP Probook 430 G3 Notebook. Sound is not working when using Ubuntu. While it is ok with windows. Details of the error are : http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=832b88c5ee92681319c392a7c140710f51f9044d
Please give some tried and tested response.

Comment: You appear to have two audio channels associated with you HDMI connection: `card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]` and
`card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]`, can you select between them from the preferences menu?

Comment: In system settings -> Sound -> in Output Sound though -> no device is available

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution - it works on my Probook:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg4846225.html

Comment: link only answers are frowned on ... instead populate with self contained

Comment: Probook's speakers are working now, but not detecting the headphone. When I am connecting the headphone sound is coming form speaker as well as the headphone.